# Timeout error always occurs when tried to test firestore security rules with emulator

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-tools

I tried to test firestore security rules with emulator, but timeout error always occur...
Please let me know if you have the same phenomenon or have a solution.

**Test result**

Start emulator

```
% firebase serve --only firestore
```

Run test

```
% yarn test
yarn run v1.19.2
$ jest
 FAIL  tests/firestore.test.ts (7.123s)
  Firestore Security Rule
    ✕ sample1 (5044ms)

  ● Firestore Security Rule › sample1

    : Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

      30 |   });
      31 |
    > 32 |   test("sample1", async () => {
         |   ^
      33 |     const db = createAuthApp();
      34 |     const user = usersRef(db).doc("test");
      35 |     await firebase.assertSucceeds(user.set({ name: "John" }));

      at new Spec (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Spec.js:116:22)
      at Suite.<anonymous> (tests/firestore.test.ts:32:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/firestore.test.ts:16:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.038s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

**Environment**

※Firestore security rule is allowing everything because of sample

■firestore.test.ts

```
import * as firebase from "@firebase/testing";
import * as fs from "fs";

const PROJECT_ID = "firestore-rule-test";
const RULES_PATH = "firestore.rules";

// Create Firestore app with auth
const createAuthApp = (auth?: object): firebase.firestore.Firestore => {
  return firebase
    .initializeTestApp({ projectId: RULES_PATH, auth: auth })
    .firestore();
};

const usersRef = (db: firebase.firestore.Firestore) => db.collection("user");

describe("Firestore Security Rule", () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await firebase.loadFirestoreRules({
      projectId: PROJECT_ID,
      rules: fs.readFileSync(RULES_PATH, "utf8")
    });
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await firebase.clearFirestoreData({ projectId: PROJECT_ID });
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await Promise.all(firebase.apps().map(app => app.delete()));
  });

  test("sample1", async () => {
    const db = createAuthApp();
    const user = usersRef(db).doc("test");
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(user.set({ name: "John" }));
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(user.get());
  });
});;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `.initializeTestApp({ projectId: RULES_PATH, auth: auth })` be `.initializeTestApp({ projectId: PROJECT_ID, auth: auth })`?

Comment: Have you tried changing Jest's timeout using `--testTimeout=<number>` to something like `30000` (30 seconds) and seeing if it's just taking a longer time than expected?

Comment: @samthecodingman
OH, you're right.
Test worked after fix `.initializeTestApp({ projectId: RULES_PATH, auth: auth })` to `.initializeTestApp({ projectId: PROJECT_ID, auth: auth })`.
It's my careless mistake
Thanks for pointing.

Comment: I've converted my comments into an answer for acceptance. Glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `createAuthApp()` function, you are initialising the test application with a project ID of `RULES_PATH` but in your tests you are loading security rules using a project ID of `PROJECT_ID`.

Changing

```js
.initializeTestApp({ projectId: RULES_PATH, auth: auth })
```

to

```js
.initializeTestApp({ projectId: PROJECT_ID, auth: auth })
```

should fix your issue.

In case that it doesn't solve the issue, you can change the Jest timeout to more than 5 seconds using `--testTimeout=<number of ms>` to give the test more time to complete.

Lastly, for clarity, consider renaming `createAuthApp` to `createFirestoreInstance` as "create Auth" implies something to do with the `FirebaseAuth` class.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
But when I tried to set `auth` like `auth: ({ uid: 'alice', admin: true });` when `firebase.initializeTestApp`, same timeout error occurred even after timeout extended
(the error didn't happen if auth info is empty )
Do you know something?

Comment: I won't be able to help in detail immediately (off to work), but you can try changing the Jest timeout or surrounding your `await ...` calls in `try`-`catch` blocks.